# Starting a Validator, It works, but node is behind by many slots

Tags: rpc, node

**curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"getHealth"}'**

response as follows:
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32005,"message":"Node is behind by 20352 slots","data":{"numSlotsBehind":20352}},"id":1}

**Node is behind by many slots, And then it gets bigger and bigger, Far from the main network.**

Here is the command to run the validator:
--identity /home/solana/validator-keypair.json 
--known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 
--known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ 
--known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ 
--known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S 
--only-known-rpc 
--full-rpc-api 
--no-voting 
--ledger ledger 
--rpc-port 8899 
--private-rpc 
--no-port-check 
--dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 
--entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d 
--wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record 
--limit-ledger-size 
--log /home/solana/logs/solana-validator.log

Comment: Unfortunately, your machine might not have high enough specs to keep up with the network, or your bandwidth is too low to receive and send all messages required to run the network. Take a look at your metrics like CPU usage, memory usage, bandwidth usage, and IOPS to see where the bottleneck might be.